# Is it possible to add auto-completion into external code editors for Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

I just started using Unity with Visual Studio Code and got it up and running to use it instead of the default code editor but VSC doesnt display auto-completion and I am wondering if it is even possible to add this feature into Visual Studio Code and if yes, how to do so.

Comment: Did you follow [this guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity) thoroughly? The screenshots on that link do show working autocompletion. You may also need various C#/.net Core and Unity extensions installed.